# Java ArrayList Issues

Tags: java, arrays, variables, arraylist, reference

I am trying to allow an "Admin" class to create multiple arrays. However, everytime that this loop runs it seems to delete the previous array that was created.

```
   do { 
                System.out.println("\nWhat do you want "
                 + "the name of your line to be?: ");

              String lineName= keyboard1.nextLine();


   System.out.println("\n\nCongratulations! \n"+ "Your "+ lineName +
          " queue has been created! \n");


       //Create an array that will hold "User" information.
        ArrayList<User>queue=new ArrayList<>();


        //Create an array of arrays to allow "User" to see all "lines" available to them.
        ArrayList<String>totalLines=new ArrayList<>();
            `//Add the array name to the array of arrays.     
               `totalLines.add(lineName);
        //Show Admin all of their lines.
         System.out.println("Here is a list of all of your lines: \n");
       for (String s:totalLines)
       {

           System.out.println(s);

       }

             //Ask admin if they want to create another line.
             System.out.println("\nDo you wish to add another line?\n"
                + "\nType:Yes or No?");

                 y = keyboard1.nextLine();
      } while ("Yes".equals(y)||"yes".equals(y));
```

> I am learning Java in school and I am trying my best...still not familiar with many tools in Java as we have only covered the basics so far, but I am pretty sure that my problem is that the variable "lineName" is writing over the previous ArrayList instance created. Am I on to something?

Comment: Yes, you are on to something.

Comment: Your code don't compile

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're instantiating a new `ArrayList` on each round. You need to do it outside the loop:

```
ArrayList<String>totalLines=new ArrayList<>();
do {
//...
```